# Communications link failureThe last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, birt

I am getting below error can any one suggest

```
May 28, 2020 12:31:25 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager$DriverClassLoader constructor()
FINER: ENTRY
May 28, 2020 12:31:25 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException JDBCException
FINE: odajdbc.GetConnectionError
May 28, 2020 12:31:25 PM org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ConnectionManager openConnection
SEVERE: Unable to open connection.
org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: There is an error in get connection, Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server..
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.doConnect(JDBCDriverManager.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.getConnection(JDBCDriverManager.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.Connection.connectByUrl(Connection.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.Connection.open(Connection.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaConnection.open(OdaConnection.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSource.newConnection(DataSource.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSource.open(DataSource.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.DataSourceRuntime.openOdiDataSource(DataSourceRuntime.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.openDataSource(QueryExecutor.java:437)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.prepareExecution(QueryExecutor.java:325)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedQuery.doPrepare(PreparedQuery.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.produceQueryResults(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.execute(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedOdaDSQuery.execute(PreparedOdaDSQuery.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.execute(DataRequestSessionImpl.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.GetParameterDefinitionTask.executeQuery(GetParameterDefinitionTask.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.GetParameterDefinitionTask.getResultSetForParameter(GetParameterDefinitionTask.java:1374)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.GetParameterDefinitionTask.getChoicesFromParameterQuery(GetParameterDefinitionTask.java:1348)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.GetParameterDefinitionTask.doGetSelectionList(GetParameterDefinitionTask.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.GetParameterDefinitionTask.getSelectionList(GetParameterDefinitionTask.java:451)
    at com.jataayu.reportapp.business.birt.BIRTParamBean.getParameter(BIRTParamBean.java:234)
    at com.jataayu.reportapp.business.birt.BIRTParamBean.getParamMap(BIRTParamBean.java:118)
    at com.jataayu.reportapp.controller.reportmgmt.ReportViewController.manageParamsInSession(ReportViewController.java:2878)
    at com.jataayu.reportapp.controller.reportmgmt.ReportViewController.getBaseReportView(ReportViewController.java:2177)
    at com.jataayu.reportapp.controller.reportmgmt.ReportViewController.createHTMLFileHandler(ReportViewController.java:1354)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController.invokeNamedMethod(MultiActionController.java:471)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController.handleRequestInternal(MultiActionController.java:408)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.jataayu.reportapp.utils.ResponseHeaderFilter.doFilter(ResponseHeaderFilter.java:163)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

May 28, 2020 12:31:25 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.GetParameterDefinitionTask getResultSetForParameter
WARNING: An exception occurred during processing. Please see the following message for details:
Cannot open the connection for the driver: org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.
    org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: There is an error in get connection, Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server..
org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.api.AdapterException: An exception occurred during processing. Please see the following message for details:
Cannot open the connection for the driver: org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.
    org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: There is an error in get connection, Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server..
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.execute(DataRequestSessionImpl.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.GetParameterDefinitionTask.executeQuery(GetParameterDefinitionTask.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.GetParameterDefinitionTask.getResultSetForParameter(GetParameterDefinitionTask.java:1374)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.GetParameterDefinitionTask.getChoicesFromParameterQuery(GetParameterDefinitionTask.java:1348)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.GetParameterDefinitionTask.doGetSelectionList(GetParameterDefinitionTask.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.GetParameterDefinitionTask.getSelectionList(GetParameterDefinitionTask.java:451)
    at com.jataayu.reportapp.business.birt.BIRTParamBean.getParameter(BIRTParamBean.java:234)
    at com.jataayu.reportapp.business.birt.BIRTParamBean.getParamMap(BIRTParamBean.java:118)
    at com.jataayu.reportapp.controller.reportmgmt.ReportViewController.manageParamsInSession(ReportViewController.java:2878)
    at com.jataayu.reportapp.controller.reportmgmt.ReportViewController.getBaseReportView(ReportViewController.java:2177)
    at com.jataayu.reportapp.controller.reportmgmt.ReportViewController.createHTMLFileHandler(ReportViewController.java:1354)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController.invokeNamedMethod(MultiActionController.java:471)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController.handleRequestInternal(MultiActionController.java:408)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.jataayu.reportapp.utils.ResponseHeaderFilter.doFilter(ResponseHeaderFilter.java:163)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.OdaDataException: Cannot open the connection for the driver: org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.
    org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: There is an error in get connection, Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server..
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ExceptionHandler.newException(ExceptionHandler.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSource.newConnection(DataSource.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSource.open(DataSource.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.DataSourceRuntime.openOdiDataSource(DataSourceRuntime.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.openDataSource(QueryExecutor.java:437)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.prepareExecution(QueryExecutor.java:325)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedQuery.doPrepare(PreparedQuery.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.produceQueryResults(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.execute(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedOdaDSQuery.execute(PreparedOdaDSQuery.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.execute(DataRequestSessionImpl.java:651)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: There is an error in get connection, Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server..
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.doConnect(JDBCDriverManager.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.getConnection(JDBCDriverManager.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.birt.rep
```

Comment: Please explain the problem. Tell us what you are trying to do and show a cleaned minimum code that reproduces this exception

Comment: Please refer to this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql]

Comment: It looks like a communication issue from the log. Somehow you are not able to connect to your data source. You should check if your configuration is correct and access to data source over network etc.